# How to globally replace one annotation type with another?

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, findbugs

I would like to replace one annotation type with another, throughout a large codebase.

This requires updating `import` statements and the annotations themselves.

Is there a mechanism to do this in the Eclipse IDE other than possibly naive textual search/replace?

For example:

```
import edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.NonNull;
...
    public @NonNull Integer
    foo( @NonNull Integer arg0 ) { ... }
```

Needs to be updated to:

```
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
...
    public @Nonnull Integer
    foo( @Nonnull Integer arg0 ) { ... }
```

Comment: In Eclipse, you can refactor method signatures but unfortunately that does not seem to cover their annotations.

Comment: Hello, Andy You need to run the procedure described by @gknicker twice. BTW +1 :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy in Eclipse.

1. From the *Search* menu choose *File...*
2. Set *Containing text:* to, for example, `edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.NonNull` and click the *Search* button.
3. In the Search results view, use the context menu *Remove Selected Matches* as necessary to remove matches that shouldn't be replaced
4. Right-click one of the results (context menu) and choose *Replace all...*
5. In the *Replace Text Matches* dialog, enter the replacement phrase `javax.annotation.Nonnull` in the *With:* box and click *OK*

The above would replace the `import`s, then you'd go through these steps again to replace the `@NotNull` uses.

If you prefer to use the refactoring tool, there is a way to go about this. But it's pretty involved, especially if you don't have access to the source code of the identifier you wish to move away from.

1. If the identifier being referenced is not under your control, then put it under your control through whatever manipulation necessary. For example, let's say you're using a third-party annotation `edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.NonNull` from a jar file. Ideally you'd have access to the source code, but you could also stub out the annotation. In any case, you'd remove the third-party jar file from your project and replace it with source code in your project, then get a clean build.
2. With the source in question now under your control, `Refactor->Rename...` it to the target name then `Refactor->Move...` it to the target package. You might have to create the package in your project first.
3. Finally, if applicable, delete the imposter you've just created, so that the real one can take its rightful place.
4. Any other temporary package cleanup as necessary.

Comment: This procedure must be executed twice.

Comment: There's also a "Replace..." button on the "Search>File..." dialog itself. But it's still two text-based search/replaces per annotation type. I was curious if there was a single refactoring-like operation that replaced one type with another, and was guaranteed to affect nothing else. (That said, I think the possibility of false positives in the example case and our codebase is very low.)

Comment: @AndyThomas For what it's worth, I've done such refactorings in Eclipse before, using the method outlined in my updated answer.

Comment: @gknicker - I had thought of that, but unfortunately have a *lot* of projects, each with its own classpath. I suspect there is no dedicated mechanism in Eclipse for this task. You've covered two reasonable workarounds.

Comment: I used the second method to do exactly this. I removed the FB JAR first, made a dummy annotation by fixing the resulting problem, moved and renamed it to match the target as described, and finally deleted the stub. Worked great!